# Create a project using my app as a starter in Phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

My app's git repository contain only the `www` folder and so it looks like this:

```
css
img
js
res
config.xml
icon.png
index.html
```

To start development I need to:

1. Clone my app into `www-app`
2. Create a phonegap app `phonegap create testapp com.example.testapp "Test"`
3. remove `testapp/www` and copy `www-app` to `testapp/www`

Is there a easier to way to set this up?  Maybe I can specify a project to build from on `phonegap create` instead of the [phonegap-start](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start) project.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this with phonegap CLI but cordova CLI can copy the initial contents from a project  with `--copy-from` option, so something like `phonegap create testapp com.example.testapp "Test" --copy-from www-app` may possibly work. Alternately you can create the project using Cordova CLI with `cordova create testapp com.example.testapp "Test" --copy-from www-app`and continue with phonegap.