# How to initialize a Cordova project using CLI if I only have the www directory of the project?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I'm new to Phonegap/Cordova and I installed the latest Cordova CLI via npm. I have a couple of projects that I want to build/run but the root dir seems to be only what you'd find on a www directory of a Cordova project:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-anyconference (Phonegap 2.9)

https://github.com/germanviscuso/CowTipLine (Phonegap 2.0)

How can I initialize/upgrade a Cordova project with these projects? I just want to be able to build and run these project using the latest Cordova CLI. Note that the 2nd project runs on a rather old version of Phonegap.

I tried `phonegap local run android` when in the phonegap-app-anyconference directory and it doesn't work.

Best! Thx a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question (for the benefit of other developers seeing this entry). You can create a project from a source in this way:

```
cordova create MyProject --copy-from=path/to/sourceproject
```

More details here: [Create a project using my app as a starter in Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196703/create-a-project-using-my-app-as-a-starter-in-phonegap)

Comment: That was Out of This World ;)